# getting a student name from the matrix

Tags: python, list

I am learning python and working on assignment to get a new_list of student names from a student_grades list, which is in the form of matrix.

I was able to get it to the point where I got the first name from the list but can't figure out how to complete the loop so it iterates over every name on the matrix. Thank you.

```
student_grades = [
    ['Student', 'Exam 1', 'Exam 2', 'Exam 3'],
    ['Jane', '100', '90', '80'],
    ['Susan', '88', '99', '111'],
    ['Dick', '45', '56', '67']
]
student_list = []
for names in student_grades:
    #print(names)
    student_list.append(student_grades[1][0])

print(student_list)

['Jane', 'Jane', 'Jane', 'Jane']
```

Comment: Sometimes (many times) printing *stuff* can help diagnose a problem - see my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
student_list.append[names[0]]
```

The problem is that you're currently grabbing exactly the same list element on each iteration, without regard to the iteration.

Also, there's no real reason to force the column headers into your grade book -- let that be a `print` add-on detail when you print your data in that particular format.

```
student_grades = [
    ['Jane', '100', '90', '80'],
    ['Susan', '88', '99', '111'],
    ['Dick', '45', '56', '67']
]
student_list = []
for names in student_grades:
    student_list.append(names[0])

print(student_list)
```

Output:

```
['Jane', 'Susan', 'Dick']
```

Finally, I expect that you'll want to keep the scores as integers, rather than strings.

Comment: Thank you. How do I iterate over each element in the nested list? This is I think where my struggle is.

Comment: That's another loop, something like `for score in names[1:]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to get index

```
student_list = []
for idx in range(len(student_grades)):
    student_list.append(student_grades[idx][0])

print(student_list)#['Student', 'Jane', 'Susan', 'Dick']
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what nested loops are?

if not continue ->

first a nested loop is a loop inside a loop so the first loop would iterate through the each list in the List of lists, then the second loop inside the first loop would iterate through every object in that list (exam score).

ex:

```
lst = [['Jane', 100, 90, 80], ['Susan', '88', '99', '111'], ['Dick', 46, 56, 67]]
std_lst = []
for i in lst:
   # i is the list now like (['Jane', 100, 90, 80])
   std_lst.append(i[0])

# std_lst = ['Jane', 'Susan', 'Dick']
```